# HTML5 Canvas best way to plot a bunch of resizable graphs

Tags: javascript, optimization, plot, graph, html5-canvas

I am currently creating some artsy background for my website with a bunch of randomly generated curve plots.

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/156Uc.png)

So far, I am using Html5 Canvas and I recreate the whole every time the window is resized to fit the new width of the canvas. The data all lies in x,y ~ [0,1],[0,1] and is then scaled to fit the window. This is how I set up the canvas transformation:

```
ctx.resetTransform();
ctx.scale(c.width, c.height);
```

Since the basic data does not change, I was hoping I could just adjust the canvas size (which deletes all data) and the transformation to update the plots (although I guess I might run into trouble concerning the stroke width, when stroking the lines in the [0,1] space).
Is there any more efficient way for me to redraw all these plots (for example storing all the line-paths somehow) or do I really have to loop through everything again and recreate the whole scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Path2D`

Use  [`Path2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) to create the content once then render to the scale as needed.

For example

```
const pathStroke = new Path2D(), pathFill = new Path2D();
var i;
for (i = 0; i <= 1; i += 1 / 100) {
    pathStroke.lineTo(i, Math.sin(i * Math.PI * 8) * 0.1 + 0.2);
    pathFill.lineTo(i, Math.sin(i * Math.PI * 16) * 0.1 + 0.4);
}
for (i = 0; i <= 1; i += 1 / 100) {
    pathFill.lineTo((1-i), Math.cos((i-i) * Math.PI * 13) * 0.1 + 0.5);
}
```

Then to render the content

```
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.setTransform(canvas.width, 0, 0, canvas.height, 0, 0);
ctx.stroke(pathStroke);
ctx.fill(pathFill);
```

### Demo

Switch to full page to see content re-rendered and scaled.

- The function `createPaths` adds content to the two paths `pathStroke` and `pathFill`
- The function `renderContent` renders the content in the paths scaled to fit the canvas. 
  The resize event just calls this function again.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const pathStroke = new Path2D(), pathFill = new Path2D();
createPaths();
renderContent();
addEventListener("resize", renderContent);

function createPaths() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i <= 1; i += 1 / 1000) {
      pathStroke.lineTo(i * i, Math.sin(i * Math.PI * 8) * 0.05 + 0.1);
      pathFill.lineTo(i, Math.sin(i * Math.PI * 11) * 0.4 * i ** 0.5  + 0.6);
  }
  for (i = 0; i <= 1; i += 1 / 1000) {
      if (i === 0) {
          pathStroke.moveTo((1-i), Math.sin(i * i * Math.PI * 8) * (i * 0.1) + 0.2);      
      } else {
          pathStroke.lineTo((1-i), Math.sin(i * i * Math.PI * 9) * (i * 0.1) + 0.2);       
      }
      pathFill.lineTo((1-i), Math.cos((1-i) * Math.PI * 13) * 0.3 * i * i + 0.7);
  }
}


function renderContent() {
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height= innerHeight;
    
    // scale line width 2 pixels
    ctx.lineWidth = 2 / Math.max(canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.setTransform(canvas.width, 0, 0, canvas.height, 0, 0);
    ctx.stroke(pathStroke);
    ctx.fill(pathFill);
}
```

```css
body { padding: 0px }
canvas {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks.
Although, I find it very frustrating that it's not possible to keep the stroke width at 1 pixel.. I found that creating the paths while having the transformation set and resetting the transformation before calling stroke() worked:
```
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.setTransform(canvas.width, 0, 0, canvas.height, 0, 0);
ctx.beginPath();
//ctx.lineTo etc
ctx.resetTransform();
ctx.stroke();
```
I didn't see an immediate way to apply this to paths created by Path2D. Maybe it's time to look into SVG..

Comment: @lain Yes it is a shame about not being able to change the transform after a `path2D`. It would have been nice to have `ctx.beginPath` accept a `path2D` which would  allowed such manipulation. straight forward.

Comment: So I finally discovered that you can create a new path and then call `path.addPath(oldPath, m)` where m is the Transformation matrix, and then stroke with 1px. This option should have been implemented in the default constructor or at least as a function...

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is not going to change why not use svg instead of having all the data first being saved in some place and having whole lot of logic being written to draw that on canvas.

There are sites available to convert you image to svg. All you have to do is make some changes which you seem most fit to your needs and you are done.

some examples: [Trajan column](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Trajans-Column-lower-animated.svg)

Comment: I haven't done much with svg so far, although it does sound more appropriate. How easy would it be to achieve the same with svg in javascript? Can it be done without external libraries? How would this look performance-wise?
Just to clarify: The data doesn't change after the page is loaded, but is randomly generated via js.